# PhotoCamera.Orientation is always 90?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone

Why is the Orientation property of PhotoCamera class always 90, irrespective of if I am switching from landscape to portrait or vice versa?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.camera.orientation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) documentation describes this property as :

> Gets the number of degrees that the viewfinder brush needs to be rotated clockwise to align with the camera sensor.

If this is the case, **shouldn't the Orientation property be 0, when I hold the camera in LandscapeLeft mode**?

What am I missing here?

[Sample steps to reproduce this]

Download sample code from this [microsoft](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Camera-Sample-52dae359/file/62725/10/Basic%20Camera%20Sample.zip) link.

In the MainPage.xaml set
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"

In the MainPage.xaml.cs, modify the OnOrientationChanged method to print the Camera.Orientation.

```
protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cam != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cam.Orientation.ToString());
```

Comment: does the device you are using have a gyroscope? If not, it cannot measure orientation.

Comment: Yes. I am using Nokia Lumia 820.

Comment: @ColinE, In case if the device doens't have gyroscope, can't an accelerometer give the orientation?